# C# HttpWebRequest Timed Out

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler

Using Fiddler, I mimicked all the headers that were sent by an actual browser (Chrome).
Then I tried to call the function by

```
GetResponse("https://www.example.com/");
```

But get error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The operation has timed out

Code:

```
public static string GetResponse(string sURL, CookieContainer cookies = null, string sParameters = "", string sUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36")
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        httpRequest.UserAgent = sUserAgent;

        if (cookies == null) cookies = new CookieContainer();
        httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        httpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

        httpRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        httpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        if (sParameters == "")
        {
            httpRequest.Method = "GET";
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpRequest.ContentLength = sParameters.Length;

            using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sParameters), 0, sParameters.Length);
            }

        }
                    
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        
        string sResponse;
        using (Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(936));
            sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return sResponse;
    }
```

After inspecting in Fiddler, compared to a regular browser action, the missing part is cookies, however a cookiecontainer has been attached to the httpwebrequest object in the code. So I don't know why the cookie is missing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Delete the cookies and try again.  A cookie has a timeout so once a cookies is returned from you do not need to send anther cookies as long as you are logged into the server.

Comment: This kind of WebServer relies on strict security (for its transactions). Strict security is based (in this case) also on the Browser type and version. Thus, you need to specify a User-Agent. DO NOT specify a User-Agent that uses HSTS for additional security (like recent versions of FireFox). Use IE 11 Header. If you need something written down, let me know. Note: You don't need a Certificate Validation callback for the main site. It might be needed further down the path.

Comment: @jdweng an newly created cookiecontainer with no cookie inside was attached to the httpwebrequest object. It happens before I could login.

Comment: Cookies are passed (it uses Set-Cookie) only after a connection has been established. You'll get 7 of them, this case.

Comment: @Jimi When I tried IE 11 user-agent, or MS Edge user-agent, I got "<br>Your browser is no longer supported by BestBuy" inside the very short response body. Would you share your code? Thanks!

Comment: `httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";`

Comment: @Jimi Thanks! I can get the cookies now. However by inspecting in Fiddler the cookies are different from browser sent cookies, and with these cookies I can only get a page saying "Your browser is no longer supported by BestBuy". Any idea?

Comment: In the same method: `CookieContainer cookiecontainer = new CookieContainer(); httpRequest.CookieContainer = cookiecontainer;`. Don't store them, it's useless. Session cookies will expire but you don't have a backing smart browser that act on those. You just have to give means to exchange them while you're connected. Nothing more. Comment out `Headers.Add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");` You can't do that.

Comment: @Jimi I know I'm asking a lot, but would you point me to some example or document on how to do the exchange? Best regards!

Comment: What do you need to exchange? Mind that I know about protocols, I'm not an expert in BestBuy stuff.

Comment: @Jimi I'm trying to write a web crawler to do some statistics, therefore I need to get the correct webpage response of several websites. The method I use above works for some but not for this one. For example, when I request the homepage of bestbuy, I only got "Your browser is no longer supported by BestBuy", instead of the actual homepage.

Comment: What is not working with this server response? Have you connected to `https://www.bestbuy.com/?intl=nosplash` to get to the main english page? What it is it that you can't get out of it? I don't get the message you describe. The full page is returned. I can pass it to a WebBrowser to see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176000/discussion-between-cal-and-jimi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look a lot of stuff, but you don't need to be concerned with what this all does right now.

Just create a `Button` on a `Form`, then make async it's `Click` event handler as shown here (the main methods here use all async `Http/IO` .Net methods).
The remaining code just needs to be pasted (in the same Form, to make it quick).

The `StreamObject` used to pass data back and forth, after the connection is completed will contain some informations about the WebSite specified in its `ResourceURI` property (as below).

The `StreamObject.Payload` is the complete `Html` page, decoded using it's internal CodePage or the CodePage detected by the server.
If you want to see it, just pass it to a WebBrowser.

> Note:
>  I might have left out something, adapting this to be posted here. This will be immediately
>   obvious.
>  In case, tell me what it is and I'll update this
>   code.
>   Also:
>   **Disable Fiddler**!

```
Visual Studio Version: VS Pro 15.7.5
.Net FrameWork: 4.7.1


private async void TestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StreamObject sObject = new StreamObject()
    {
        ResourceURI = new Uri(@"https://www.bestbuy.com/?intl=nosplash"),
        ProcessStream = true
    };

    sObject = await HTTP_GetStream(sObject);
    Console.WriteLine(sObject.Payload.Length);
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class StreamObject
{
    public StreamObject()
    {
        this.Cookies = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public Stream ContentStream { get; set; }
    public bool ProcessStream { get; set; }
    public Uri ResourceURI { get; set; }
    public Uri ResponseURI { get; set; }
    public string Referer { get; set; }
    public string Payload { get; set; }
    public string ServerType { get; set; }
    public string ServerName { get; set; }
    public IPAddress[] ServerIP { get; set; }
    public string ContentName { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string ContentCharSet { get; set; }
    public string ContentLanguage { get; set; }
    public long ContentLenght { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public WebExceptionStatus WebException { get; set; }
    public string WebExceptionDescription { get; set; }
    public CookieContainer Cookies { get; set; }
}

const uint COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION = 0x80131509;


public async Task<StreamObject> HTTP_GetStream(StreamObject RequestObject)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestObject.ResourceURI.ToString().Trim()))
        return null;

    MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest;
    CookieContainer CookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    HttpStatusCode StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                           SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += TlsValidationCallback;

    httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(RequestObject.ResourceURI);

    try
    {
        HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(ref httpRequest, CookieJar, RequestObject);
        httpRequest.Method = "GET";
        using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync())
        {
            Stream ResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            //SslProtocols Protocol = ExtractSslProtocol(ResponseStream);

            if (StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                await ResponseStream.CopyToAsync(memstream);
                RequestObject.ContentStream = memstream;
                RequestObject.ResponseURI = httpResponse.ResponseUri;
                RequestObject.ContentLenght = memstream.Length;
                RequestObject.ContentCharSet = httpResponse.CharacterSet ?? string.Empty;
                RequestObject.ContentLanguage = httpResponse.Headers["Content-Language"] ?? string.Empty;
                RequestObject.ContentType = httpResponse.ContentType.ToLower();
                if (RequestObject.ContentType.IndexOf(@"/") > -1)
                {
                    do {
                        RequestObject.ContentType = RequestObject.ContentType.Substring(RequestObject.ContentType.IndexOf(@"/") + 1);
                        if (RequestObject.ContentType.IndexOf(@"/") < 0)
                            break;
                    } while (true);
                    if (RequestObject.ContentType.IndexOf(";")> -1)
                        RequestObject.ContentType = RequestObject.ContentType.Substring(0, RequestObject.ContentType.IndexOf(@";"));
                    RequestObject.ContentType = "." + RequestObject.ContentType;
                }
                RequestObject.ContentName = httpResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] ?? string.Empty;
                if (RequestObject.ContentName.Length == 0)
                    RequestObject.ContentName = RequestObject.ResourceURI.Segments.Last();
                RequestObject.ServerType = httpResponse.Server;
                RequestObject.ServerName = RequestObject.ResponseURI.DnsSafeHost;
                RequestObject.ServerIP = await Dns.GetHostAddressesAsync(RequestObject.ServerName);
                RequestObject.StatusCode = StatusCode;
                RequestObject.StatusDescription = httpResponse.StatusDescription;
                if (RequestObject.ProcessStream)
                    RequestObject.Payload = ProcessResponse(RequestObject.ContentStream,
                                                            Encoding.GetEncoding(RequestObject.ContentCharSet), 
                                                            httpResponse.ContentEncoding);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException exW)
    {
        if (exW.Response != null)
        {
            RequestObject.StatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)exW.Response).StatusCode;
            RequestObject.StatusDescription = ((HttpWebResponse)exW.Response).StatusDescription;
        }
        RequestObject.WebException = exW.Status;
        RequestObject.WebExceptionDescription = exW.Message;

    }
    catch (Exception exS)
    {
        if ((uint)exS.HResult == COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION)
        {
            //RequestObject.WebException = PingHostAddress("8.8.8.8", 500) > 0
            //                            ? WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure
            //                            : WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure;
            RequestObject.WebException = WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure;
            RequestObject.WebExceptionDescription = RequestObject.WebException.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            RequestObject.WebException = WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled;
            RequestObject.WebExceptionDescription = RequestObject.WebException.ToString();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= TlsValidationCallback;
    }

    RequestObject.Cookies = httpRequest.CookieContainer;
    RequestObject.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    return RequestObject;

}   //HTTP_GetStream


private bool TlsValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate CACert, X509Chain CAChain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    //if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    //    return true;

    X509Certificate2 _Certificate = new X509Certificate2(CACert);
    //X509Certificate2 _CACert = new X509Certificate2(@"[localstorage]/ca.cert");
    //CAChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(_CACert);


    //X509Certificate2 cert =  GetCertificateFromStore(thumbprint);
    X509Certificate2 cert = (X509Certificate2)CACert;

    //CspKeyContainerInfo cpsKey = (CspKeyContainerInfo)((RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key).CspKeyContainerInfo;
    //if (cert.HasPrivateKey) { RSA rsaKey = (RSA)cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(); }
    //if (cpsKey.Accessible) { Console.WriteLine("Exportable: {0}", cpsKey.Exportable); }

    // next line generates exception "Key does not exist"
    //bool isexportable = provider.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable;

    CAChain.Build(_Certificate);
    foreach (X509ChainStatus CACStatus in CAChain.ChainStatus)
    {
        if ((CACStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError) &
            (CACStatus.Status != X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private void HTTP_RequestHeadersInit(ref HttpWebRequest httpreq, CookieContainer cookiecontainer, StreamObject postdata)
{
    httpreq.Date = DateTime.Now;
    httpreq.Timeout = 30000;
    httpreq.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
    httpreq.CookieContainer = cookiecontainer;
    httpreq.KeepAlive = true;
    httpreq.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    httpreq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    httpreq.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 30000;
    httpreq.Referer = postdata.Referer;
    httpreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident / 7.0; rv: 11.0) like Gecko";
    //httpreq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0";
    httpreq.Accept = "ext/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    httpreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-US;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    httpreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8");
    httpreq.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache");
    httpreq.Headers.Add("DNT", "1");

    if (postdata != null && postdata.UseProxy)
    {
        if (postdata.ProxyParameters != null)
        {
            if ((postdata.ProxyParameters.Host.Length > 0))
            {
                httpreq.Proxy = new WebProxy(postdata.ProxyParameters.Host, postdata.ProxyParameters.Port);
            }
            else
            {
                httpreq.Proxy = new WebProxy(postdata.ProxyParameters.Uri, postdata.ProxyParameters.BypassLocal);
            }
                httpreq.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(postdata.ProxyParameters.Credentials.UserID,
                                                                  postdata.ProxyParameters.Credentials.Password);
        }
        else
        {
            httpreq.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        }
    }
}


private string ProcessResponse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, string ContentEncoding)
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    stream.Position = 0;
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    gzipStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                };
            }
            else if (ContentEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                using (DeflateStream deflStream = new DeflateStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    deflStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memStream);
            }

            memStream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStream, encoding))
            {
                html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                html = DecodeMetaCharSetEncoding(memStream, html, encoding);
            };
        };
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return html;
}


private string DecodeMetaCharSetEncoding(Stream memStream, string _html, Encoding _encode)
{
    Match _match = new Regex("<meta\\s+.*?charset\\s*=\\s*\"?(?<charset>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\"?",
                             RegexOptions.Singleline |
                             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(_html);
    if (_match.Success)
    {
        string charset = _match.Groups["charset"].Value.ToLower() ?? "utf-8";
        if ((charset == "unicode") | (charset == "utf-7") | (charset == "utf-16"))
           charset = "utf-8";

        try
        {
            Encoding metaEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
            if (_encode.WebName != metaEncoding.WebName)
            {
                memStream.Position = 0L;
                using (StreamReader recodeReader = new StreamReader(memStream, metaEncoding))
                { _html = recodeReader.ReadToEnd().Trim(); }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            _html = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _html = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    return _html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With some changes (to the proxy boolean) I was able to run the code and it does the magic! I thought it would be minor changes to my original code but thank you for taking all the trouble to provide the working code. Appreciated!

Comment: @Cal  Your code was missing the Server Certificate Validation callback, which is a no-go for many sites that use Https/Ssl (not in this case - at first - as I said). It was mostly fine for the rest. The code I posted was meant to set both of us on the the *same page* :) about what's happening. I hate unresolved problems. I'm glad it worked for you. -- If you use Fiddler, note that it can simulate a Web Browser (changing the `User-Agent` header). This can mess things up (hence, the warning).

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, the code has been working great, until I tried to use a different User Agent. The one you have in the code is IE11, but if I replace it with Chrome 71, I got "The operation has timed out" error. The UA string is "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36". I would much appreciate it if you can take a look. Best.

Comment: Try with this User-Agent and see whether you get the same result: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0`. I suppose it should fail as well.

Comment: It also result in "The operation has timed out" error

Comment: Yep, as expected. There's a catch, using WebRequest: newer Browsers support Http 2.0 and HSTS. If you impersonate a Browser that supports these features, the Web Site will expect some interaction from the Browser and will wait until it receives a response. Or until it times out. Use an older User-Agent string.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to mimic new browser? What kind of response is expected from the WebRequest? By viewing Fiddler I see there are several requests to the website after the main response has been received. Could it be one of these requests?

Comment: I've never tested this with `WebRequest`. I doubt it can be done, it's not part of the protocol that this class handles. Try `HttpClient` instead.